# Rewrite rules cause infinite redirect loop

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My folder structure looks like this:

```
/var/www/.htaccess
/var/www/site/index.php
/var/www/site/images/test.png
```

Where the `.htaccess` file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond /site/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site/index.php [L,QSA]
```

Essentially, I want to rewrite all URLs to the /site/ directory, and have existing files simply rewrite to their paths in the `site` folder, while making any file that does not exist rewrite to `/site/index.php` instead.

The `.htaccess` file above works for `/images/test.png`, but for `/` it causes an infinite loop, as reported in the Apache error log:

```
[Sat Jun 13 21:42:04.003016 2015] [core:error] [pid 12949] [client 127.0.0.1:50560] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Sat Jun 13 21:42:04.003020 2015] [core:debug] [pid 12949] core.c(3533): [client 127.0.0.1:50560] AH00121: r->uri = /site/index.php
[Sat Jun 13 21:42:04.003022 2015] [core:debug] [pid 12949] core.c(3540): [client 127.0.0.1:50560] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /site/index.php
[Sat Jun 13 21:42:04.003033 2015] [core:debug] [pid 12949] core.c(3540): [client 127.0.0.1:50560] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /site/index.php
[Sat Jun 13 21:42:04.003035 2015] [core:debug] [pid 12949] core.c(3540): [client 127.0.0.1:50560] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /site/index.php
[Sat Jun 13 21:42:04.003037 2015] [core:debug] [pid 12949] core.c(3540): [client 127.0.0.1:50560] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /site/index.php
[Sat Jun 13 21:42:04.003038 2015] [core:debug] [pid 12949] core.c(3540): [client 127.0.0.1:50560] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /site/index.php
[Sat Jun 13 21:42:04.003040 2015] [core:debug] [pid 12949] core.c(3540): [client 127.0.0.1:50560] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /site/index.php
[Sat Jun 13 21:42:04.003041 2015] [core:debug] [pid 12949] core.c(3540): [client 127.0.0.1:50560] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /site/index.php
[Sat Jun 13 21:42:04.003048 2015] [core:debug] [pid 12949] core.c(3540): [client 127.0.0.1:50560] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /site/index.php
[Sat Jun 13 21:42:04.003049 2015] [core:debug] [pid 12949] core.c(3540): [client 127.0.0.1:50560] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /site/index.php
[Sat Jun 13 21:42:04.003050 2015] [core:debug] [pid 12949] core.c(3540): [client 127.0.0.1:50560] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /
```

According to the documentation, rewrite rules could be run again if they're in `.htaccess` files for various reasons, but I'm not sure why, or how to protect against it. I tried adding a `RewriteCond` before the second `RewriteRule` to only run the rule if the filename isn't already /site/index.php, but this causes all URLs (even existing files) to rewrite to /site/index.php.

To be more clear on what exactly I want, I want the following URIs rewritten to the following paths:

- `/` --> `/site/index.php`
- `/test` -- > `/site/index.php`
- `/images/test.png` --> `/site/images/test.png` (because the file exists)
- `/images/bla.png` --> `/site/index.php` (because the file does not exist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first `RewriteRule` never will be used because of `RewriteCond`. It always false. `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` return full path on server, no filename.

The second rule alone makes infinite loop redirecting `/site/index.php` to itself.

If you explain what you want, we try to help youto make working htaccess

**UPDATE**

```
RewriteEngine on

# if file exist only add /site/
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/site/%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /site/$1 [L]

# if no /site/ in request rewrite to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/site/
RewriteRule ^ /site/index.php [L]
```

Comment: @AngeloGeels  i do the same with the answer :)